# Calling a function with arguments within @IBAction "Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction"

Tags: xml, swift, soap, interface-builder, alamofire

[1] I have a storyboard button that should call a function to insert a value "ircc".

```
@IBAction func SelectButtonA(sender: NSButton) {
        triggerRemoteControl(irccc: "xxxx")
    }
```

[2]

```
func triggerRemoteControl(irccc: String) {
    Alamofire.request("http://192.168.2.7/sony/IRCC?",
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: ["parameter" : "value"],
                      encoding: SOAPEncoding(service: "urn:schemas-sony-com:service:IRCC:1",
                                             action: "X_SendIRCC", IRCCC: irccc)).responseString { response in
                                                print(response)
```

[1] produces an error. **"Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction"**

The idea is to create a button, each with a unique IRCCC value that feeds into a function that sends an XML packet with other, constant information. The function relies on a struct that defines the SOAP encoding.

Comment: If your IBAction code is *irccc: xxxx*, the how can the compiler know that *xxxx* is a String?

Comment: Sorry, I took out the irccc string when I posted on SO. In reality, it is a string, with quotes. I'll fix that.